# include simple_list_item_1 in xml layout that gives feedback onClick

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have to rebuild the look of a clickable list item.

Therefore I have this xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_changeRoomLabel"
    style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/label_optionChangeName" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/tv_btn_changeRoom"
    layout="@android:layout/simple_list_item_1"
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
    android:clickable="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have tried a lot of different things to add in the  tag, but its always the same. When I click the list item, it doesn't show feedback. Meaning the background color of the simple_list_item does not change as it does when using a normal ListView. Nevertheless at least the onClick() is performed.

Any ideas?

P.S I've come across the simple_layout_activated_1 but it's API 11 so I cannot use it. I have mintarget 7.

EDIT:
the javacode

```
TextView options = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_btn_changeRoom);
    options.setText(m_model.getRoomName(m_roomId));
    options.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do sth
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please post your java file code.

Comment: do you want to change the background color of list when selected and return to previous color when relesed. AM I RIGHT HERE??

Comment: @NarendraPal actually I want the standard behaviour of a listelement when it's clicked. (in newer android versions the background color changes to a slight blue, in older it gets orange)
However in my case I don't want a ListView but a TextView with the same behaviour as a ListElement

Answer (score 0):

**Ok. As per your comment in discussion, I think you want your own selector when your `textView` is selected**

For this you can do this via layout file. It's very simple doing in layout using the **`selector`**

Modify you `textView` design to this.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_changeRoomLabel"
    android:background="@drawable/textBackSelector"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/label_optionChangeName" />
```

Make a file in **drawable** folder and name it as `textBackSelector.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="THE_COLOR_YOU_WANT_WHEN_PRESSED"/>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="THE_COLOR_YOU_WANT_WHEN_SELECTED"/>
    <item android:color="DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_COLOR_OF_TEXTVIEW"/>

</selector>
```

The above *xml* handle your textView background when it is selected.

Hope it help you.

Thanks

Comment: no sorry, this does not help me!
because first it has to have the native look of android on all API's and second I want the TextView in the <include /> part to work that way, and not a simple TextView